# Linux Setup Creator

Tags: linux, installation

I'm looking for a tool that's able to create "setup" packages for Linux, just like the Windows install creators do (NSIS, InstallShield, etc.). I want it to be able to present a graphical interface to the user (or ncurses based), where he can select some options and install the package.

Any ideas of such a tool? I'm aware of autopackage, but it's not exactly what I want. It focuses mostly on correctly installing the software, I want something that focuses on creating an installer that's able to copy files, edit, run scripts, etc.

Comment: What's wrong with correctly installing software? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be [loki setup](http://www.icculus.org/loki_setup/). It supports curses and gtk based setup programs. A few installer generators are cross-platform, relying on the presence of a JVM, like [VAInstall](http://vainstall.sourceforge.net/). Commercial offerings include [InstallAnywhere](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installanywhere/editions.htm).

Comment: Try also http://bitrock.com  In addition to the GUI/text 'traditional' installers, it will also allow you to generate DEB and RPM packages.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't *one*.

Installing software on linux/bsd is, usually, done by the package management system. What this package management system is depends on the linux distribution or bsd variant.

Making a package for a distribution is usually done by the distribution themselves. Mostly because they are teo many to for developers to support.

So you don't package it, let them do it.

Unless the source isn't freely distributed, then pick the distribution(s) your (potential) users are using.

Comment: I want a single binary that will work on all Linux distributions; I also don't want it to act like package, but be more like a "dropper": you run it, it shows up some options, the user chooses what he wants and selects where should the contents be dropped.

Comment: Why? What's so special about your software that it shouldn't play ball like everyone else?

Comment: It's a data processing script that requires to be deployed on more than one Linux distribution in my company and it requires some configuration, like adding acounts to the system and creating some cron jobs based on user input.. So I thought the easiest way was via a menu driven "wizard" which deployed it.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then it makes sense.

If it's big environment maybe investing time in a configuration managment system is an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Use [InstallBuilder 9](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com). It seems awesome.

[image]